# Find if there is a zero bytes file in a blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure blob container with a big amount of files (millions). I need to find out if there is any file with a file size of 0 bytes. Is there an easy way of doing it?

In case it makes any difference, the container doesn't have any tags applied.

Comment: You will need to list all blobs in the container and do the filtering on the client side.

Comment: Are you looking for code to do this? If not, you could just use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) and sort by blob size.

Comment: @Andy...Storage Explorer solution will not work as it only fetches a maximum of 5000 blobs / request (REST API restriction) so any sorting that will be done only on the fetched blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case this may help somebody else, here's the script I wrote in powershell:

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName <AccountName> -StorageAccountKey <PrimaryKey>
$ContainerName = "containerName"
$MaxReturn = 10000
$loopCount = 0
$Total = 0
$Token = $Null

do {
  $Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $ctx -Container $ContainerName -MaxCount $MaxReturn -ContinuationToken $Token

  $Total += $Blobs.Count

  foreach ($blobitem in $Blobs) {
    $loopCount += 1
    Write-Host -NoNewline "`rValidating batch: " $loopCount "/" $blobsList.Length " (Current total:" $Total ")"

    if ($blobitem.Length -eq 0) {
      Write-Host ""
      Write-Host "Zero bytes file found: " $blobitem.Name
    }
  }

  $loopCount = 0
  if ($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break; }
  $Token = $Blobs[$blobs.Count - 1].ContinuationToken;
}
While ($Token -ne $Null)

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Finished!"
```